# Python FTP SSL error while tethering on IPhone/ATT

Tags: python, iphone, macos, ssl, ftp

I have some simple ftps code, that works on my laptop when connected via WIFI. However if I use my ATT IPhones tethering capabilities the code no longer runs on my laptop and the following error is thrown:

```
*cmd* 'AUTH TLS'
*put* 'AUTH TLS\r\n'
*get* '234 Proceed with negotiation.\r\n'
*resp* '234 Proceed with negotiation.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/n/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 669, in login
    self.auth()
  File "/Users/n/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 681, in auth
    server_hostname=self.host)
  File "/Users/n/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 352, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/Users/n/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 579, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/n/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
[Finished in 52.4s with exit code 1]
```

How can I get the following example to work while using tethering?

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

url = 'url.com'
username = 'guest'
password = 'password'

ftps = FTP_TLS(url)
ftps.login(username, password)  # login anonymously before securing control channel
ftps.prot_p()          # switch to secure data connection

print ftps.nlst()

ftps.quit()
```

I have also tried including [the SSL monkey patch from this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error) with no success.

```
import ssl 
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Answer (score 1):

first set the debuglevel to 2 to print out more information, and do the comparison with the difference under WiFi and AT&T, what i can think of now is the network initiated the connection from disconnected interface, so you might can try disable them and just leave AT&T active.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I updated the answer above with the debuglevel 2 log. It's not the interface since I'm able to browser the web and comment on stack overflow.

Comment: can you remove ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context first to test out? this is just for when certificate does not match the host.

Comment: just double checked, I didn't have it in there.

Comment: case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
        {
            unsigned long e = ERR_get_error();
            if (e == 0) {
                if (ret == 0 || !obj->Socket) {
                    p = PY_SSL_ERROR_EOF;
                    errstr = "EOF occurred in violation of protocol";
the above code is in ssl.c for python 2.7, indicate there is no socket error, possible wrong interface issue, what is your at&t tether interface?

Comment: it's using `en0` for thether and for wifi.

Comment: ok, once you tether with at&t, try telnet url 21 from terminal to see if you can connect to the remote ftp port.